# Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en query builder en laravel 5.8 con lo cuál no logro tener un resultado esperado. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sql

Para el selectRaw cantidad el resultado esperado sería el numero 3, mientras que para el selectRaw cantGas el resultado sería el número 100. 
Ahora bien el resultado obtenido para cantidad es 3 y para cantGas es 300, es decir que me está multiplicando cantidad con cantGas

```
  $carros2 = DB::table('vehiculos as v')
                ->select('v.placa', 'v.marca', 'v.modelo', 'v.cantidadAsientos')
                ->selectRaw('IFNULL(count(mv.placa), 0) as cantidad')
                ->selectRaw('IFNULL(sum(phc.cantLitros), 0) as cantGas') 
                ->leftjoin('mantenimiento_vehiculars as mv', 'v.placa', '=', 'mv.placa')
                ->leftjoin('presupuesto_historico_cs as phc', 'v.placa', '=', 'phc.placa')
                ->where('v.tipo','moto')
                ->where('v.estado','Activo')
                ->groupBy('v.placa', 'v.marca', 'v.modelo', 'v.cantidadAsientos')
                ->get();
```

Comment: yo recomendaria hacer en raw ejemplo DB::select(DB::raw(" 
    SELECT  .........
));

Comment: @Bryro apoyo al comentario, de la misma manera lo manejo yo desde hace unos años.

Comment: muchas gracias, me iluminaron la mente, gracias a su respuesta logré solucionar el error, adjunto mi solució:

Comment: Db::raw('(select IFNULL(sum(phc.cantLitros), 0)
                                            from presupuesto_historico_cs as phc
                                            where phc.placa = v.placa) as cantGas')